# Nvidia X Server - Refresh rate reset at startup

Tags: nvidia, xorg, nvidia-settings

I have an issue with Ubuntu 16.04 and Nvidia X Server Settings.

When I go to *X Server Display Configuration* and select my screen, I put resolution to 1920x1080 and refresh rate to 144 Hz. Then, I save to X configuration file in */etc/X11/xorg.conf*.

However, when I restart my PC, everything is back to auto, and so refresh rate is back to 60Hz.

I checked, in startup applications, the command:

`sh -c '/usr/bin/nvidia-settings --load-config-only'` is run at startup.

How can I make my screen settings persistent? Should I modify the flag for *nvidia-settings* command run at startup? Or should I write X configuration file to another place?

---

My configuration:

- Nvidia GTX 970
- Nvidia proprietary drivers 384.111
- 1920x1080 @ 144Hz G-Sync screen

Comment: I have the same problem with Nvidia 1060 and nvidia drivers 430.26.